# Newton , Binomial Series and Power Series , and James Gregory

Tags: calculus, newton, combinatorics

After 2 month long search on the net, I was lucky enough to find a pdf on how Newton found the series for sine. It was a beautiful derivation mostly geometrical. But he used the Binomial Series.

*Now what I look for is Newton's proof (sort of proof) of the Binomial Series . I have read that he interpolated areas under circles and hyperbolas but a succinct answer jumps in terms of what he actually did without is what I am looking for. I know he made tables then followed the pattern. But there must be a lot of geometrical work too which would have led him to this point. All sorts of interpolation.*

That's what I want to understand. **What did he actually do ? What was his geometrical work regarding it as well as what was his sort Interpolation of areas**

Comment: Complete mathematical works of Newton are available on line.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko D.T Whiteside is not free. De Analysi ( series) is only in latin

Comment: Do you read Russian? Russian translation is free.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko No sorry . I don't know Russian. Only Hindi and English . I searched a lot but de Analysi is only in Latin and my ever answer is in de analysi ( I guess)

Comment: Why does the title mention Gregory, when the body doesn't at all?

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler Because Gregory was the 1st one to find an infinite series​ for a function (atan). And I have read that his logic was by far the best. I will add that in the  body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See : Derek T. Whiteside, [Newton's Discovery of the General Binomial Theorem](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3612767?Search=yes&resultItemClick=true&searchText=whiteside&searchUri=%2Faction%2FdoBasicSearch%3Ffilter%3Djid%253A10.2307%252Fj100271%26Query%3Dwhiteside%26amp%3D&seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) , *Math. Gaz.* 45 (Oct.1961).

For an English transaltion of [De analysi per aequationes numero terminorum infinitas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_analysi_per_aequationes_numero_terminorum_infinitas) (1669) see :

- [Sir Isaac Newton's Two Treatises: Of the Quadrature of Curves and Analysis by Equations of an Infinite Number of Terms, Explained : Containing the Treatises Themselves, Translated Into English, with a Large Commentary ; in which the Demonstrations are Supplied where Wanting, the Doctrine Illustrated, and the Whole Accommodated to the Capacities of Beginners, for Whom it is Chiefly Designed](https://books.google.it/books?id=z-RJAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA321) (1745), page 321-on.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! This was precisely what I was looking for . Huge thanks !